# How to detect page is refreshed in angular 16

Tags: angular, angular16

I have a code in angular 12 that working fine but not working in angular 16.

Please suggest the changes. Here is my code :

```
 this._router.events
        .pipe(filter((rs): rs is NavigationEnd => rs instanceof NavigationEnd))
        .subscribe(event => {
          if (event.id === 1 && event.url === event.urlAfterRedirects) {
            this.updateDetails();
          }
        })
```

I've implemented a functionality in a module's component, which requires a function to be called upon refreshing the page. However, currently, the function is not executing when the page is refreshed.

Comment: "Not working" is hardly enough details for us to be of any help. Also we are lacking a lot of context to be about to know what is going on. Could you please create a minimal reproduction?

Comment: I've implemented a functionality in a module's component, which requires a function to be called upon refreshing the page. However, currently, the function is not executing when the page is refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

Since your title describes detecting if the page is refreshed, I would suggest this below code, where if you refresh the page, a variable name `firstLoad` is set to false on a service that is `providedIn: 'root'`, then the router events check if the variable is false and calls the relevant method, then sets `firstLoad` to true, this will ensure the events gets fired on page refresh only!

service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class TestService {
  firstLoad = false;
  constructor() {}
}
```

main.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {
  RouterModule,
  NavigationEnd,
  Router,
  Event,
  provideRouter,
} from '@angular/router';
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';
import 'zone.js';
import { TestService } from './test.service';
import { TestComponent } from './test/test.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterModule],
  template: `
    <h1>Hello from {{ name }}!</h1>
    <a routerLink="../">
      back
    </a>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';

  constructor(private _router: Router, private testService: TestService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._router.events
      .pipe(filter((rs): rs is NavigationEnd => rs instanceof NavigationEnd))
      .subscribe((event: Event) => {
        if (!this.testService.firstLoad) {
          this.testService.firstLoad = true;
          console.log('page refreshed');
        } else {
          console.log('normal');
        }
        // if (event.id === 1 && event.url === event.urlAfterRedirects) {
        //   this.updateDetails();
        // }
      });
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [
    provideRouter([
      {
        path: 'test',
        component: TestComponent,
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'test',
        pathMatch: 'full',
      },
    ]),
  ],
});
```

The reasons I am defining on the service is because only during load this variable will be false, after the event runs, its not possible for this to be reset!

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-cxpbqn)